# How can i use VLOOKUP, MATCH functions to show multiple Data in 2 different columns with different criterias

Tags: google-sheets-formula, match, vlookup

im very new to google sheets.

Im trying to vlookup /match a product to show the containers ETA. However there are many ETAs with Different Quantities. But i need to get the earleast ETA along with the quantity(if there is any in order, there are some products that contains 0)

[image]
Picture above, Earliest ETA should show based on if there is a quantity, if its empty skip to the next earliest ETA with quantity.

ETA column should only show the date, and QTY just the quantity.

Is there a way to make a formula to search the item and quantity by the earliest ETA and is not empty in the QTY?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as [**text table**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/)(NOT as IMAGE) to the question. Adding such [md tables](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.